# CSS navigation sub-menu help... Block goes off screen

Tags: css, menu, navigation, width

I am working on a site for my brother's new plumbing company, and I am having two issues with my navigation menu. I copied some CSS from a tutorial site and tried altering it to my taste, but I can't figure out why this is happening. When I hover over the top-level menu item ("Services" in this case), the sub-menu appears as it should, but the background of the LI's extend outside of the screen. I have tried changing/setting widths on different areas of the CSS, but my limited knowledge has me scratching my head bald. I have a temporary site up, but I am testing this new version with Media Queries locally.

It won't let me post a screenshot without 10 reputation, so here is a link: http://www.sourceplumbing.com/Capture.png

The HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Leak Detection</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Water Heaters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Plumbing Fixtures</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
nav ul {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-width:550px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
nav a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 8px;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width:150px;
}
nav ul ul li {
    width:150px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    width:150px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

I do have another issue, but if I can get this figured out, I will move onto that one next. I would appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `min-width: 550px;`. This is causing ALL `<ul>` to expand to a min width of `550px`.

Taking this out will fix the problem. I guess that was there for the `nav` to stop it getting to small, in that case you should be about to put that under `nav` and not `nav ul`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/REmKU/)

---

Putting the `min-width` in the right place:

```
nav {
    min-width: 550px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/REmKU/1/)

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you Ruddy! Something so simple.